# Конвертировать DataFrame в вид корреляционной матрицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, машинное-обучение

У меня есть DataFrame:

```
  Mertix    ID
   0,6      [2,3]
   1,15     [1,2]
   0,82     [1,3]
```

Как его привести к виду:

```
    1      2      3   
1   0     1,15   0,82
2   1,15    0    0,6
3   0,82   0,6    0
```

Пробовала через :

```
pd.DataFrame(df.pivot_table(df,index=['ID'], columns=['ID'], values = ['Mertix'] , fill_value=0))
```

но не работает.

Comment: какой вывод у 'print(df.dtypes)'?

Comment: 'Mertix      float64'
'ID             object'
'dtype: object'